# Configuring Lerna for development environment: using shared package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, lerna, monorepo

I have monorepo built with `Lerna`. It has following structure:

```
packages
  - create-react-app-example
  - utils
```

`create-react-app-example` is like what `create-react-app` produces. I.e. it uses webpack for transpiling ES6/ES7 code, has hot-module-replacement on files changes etc;

`utils` package has just 1 file with some utility function. And this function is used from inside `create-react-app-example` package; It doesn't use Webpack, Babel or any other tool;

So, all pretty simple.

But I have hard times trying to configure comfortable development environment.

So there few things I want:

- to be able to use es6/es7 code inside `utils` package (code of this package should be transpiled somehow);
- automatic hot updates of main module when something changes in `utils` package;

---

The only thing came to my mind is to tweak `webpack.config.js` of `create-react-app-example`:

- change setting of babel loader, so it will not exclude `node_modules/utils` folder and will transpile it;
- and change parameters of `webpack watch` so it will detect changes in both packages

But I don't like solution above, it looks dirty for me.

May be there some more elegant solution?

Or may be I should also add webpack.config to `utils` package and somehow use it as library? If I remember correctly Webpack has such functionality.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> to be able to use es6/es7 code inside utils package (code of this
>   package should be transpiled somehow);

If you really want to keep utils as a separate package, just configure babel to transpile it separately from the CRA app. You can do this using the [babel cli](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-cli), here is an example of how to do it: https://github.com/babel/example-node-server

> automatic hot updates of main module when something changes in utils
>   package;

Your idea to configure webpack watch sounds right. Docs [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptions-ignored)

You will likely end up with 2 watches: babel transpiling the utils package, and webpack for building and bundling the CRA app.